# Overflow division operator '&/' not recognized

Tags: swift

The following playground results in an error:

```
1 &/ 0
```

Errors:

```
Operator is not known binary operator
Use of unresolved identifier '&/'
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) says it should return 0

Running xCode: Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&/` and `&%` were removed in Xcode 6.3.

Per the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-SW3):

> Unlike the `&+`, `&-`, and `&*` operators, these operators did not provide two’s-complement arithmetic behavior; they provided special case behavior for division, remainder by zero, and `Int.min`/`-1`. These tests should be written explicitly in the code as comparisons if needed.